# What's wrong i do? Django python. Displaing fields in template

Tags: python, django

Here is my model:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My view:

```
def group_detail(request, group_name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        group = Group.objects.name = group_name
        children = Child.objects.all()
        count_of_children = children.count()
        return render(request, 'group_detail.html', {'group': group,
                                                     'count_of_children': count_of_children,
                                                     'children': children})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

And I what to display in link like mysite/group/group_name details of selected group. Here I whant to display some fields, like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12"><h1>{{ group.group_name }}</h1></div>
```

And my urls

```
path('/group/<'group_name>', views.group_detail, name='group_detail')
```

Comment: This is probably what you want `group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)`

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil Thanks, you are rigth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is doing the wrong thing.

```
group = Group.objects.name = group_name
```

It is the same as doing:

```
group = group_name
Group.objects.name = group_name
```

As Ashish suggested in the comments, you can fetch the group with:

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
```

However, it would be better to use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut, to handle the case when there is no group with that name:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
group = get_object_or_404(Group, name=group_name)
```